# C# - SMO - How can I check to see if I have exclusive access to a given DB (ie check to see if a database is in use)?

Tags: c#, smo

I just spent a long time trying to figure this one out, so Id thought Id post my solution.

QUESTION:  "I am about to restore a given database in C# using SMO, and would like to check to see if I have access to the db before I restore.  How do I do that?"

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER:

Use the following code to see if a given database is in use:

```
Server srv = new Server();
if (srv.GetActiveDBConnectionCount(dbName) > 0)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Database '" + dbName + "' is currently in use");
}
```